# Функция в массиве AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, функции, массивы, flash

Возник еще вопрос, как добавить функцию в массив или почему функция в массиве пустая?

Написал функцию:

```
    private function subscribeToCallback(name:String, func:Object) : void
    {

        callbacks[name] = {'callback': func};

    }
```

Далее в конструкторе класса вызываю функцию с параметрами:

```
    subscribeToCallback("sConn", function():void {
        trace("sConn");
    });
```

И собственно далее через 2-5 секунд пытаюсь получить данные из массива, который я объявил  после создания класса:

```
    public var callbacks:Array = new Array();
```

Получить пытаюсь таким образом:

```
    trace(callbacks["sConn"].callback);
```

И в ответ получаю в консоле:

```
    function Function() {}
```

Почему же она пустая? как можно засунуть функцию в массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет.
Тут вы пытаетесь привести объект типа Function к строке, что и выходит.

```
trace(callbacks["sConn"].callback);
```

Для вызова метода который представлен этим объектом используйте функцию [call()](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#call())

```
trace(callbacks["sConn"].callback.call(null))
```

Comment: Для работы с колбеками удобная либа есть Signals. - https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals